# Please tell me what dose 1) -n option 2) sed 's?.*/??'

Tags: shell

```
if [ -n "$FULL" ]; then
    INSTALL_LIST=`cat $LIBLIST | sed 's?.*/??'`
else
    INSTALL_LIST=`ls -d *lib*/[0-9]*.[0-9][0-9] | sed 's?/.*??' | sort -u`
fi
```

Comment: Reading manuals could be very helpfull: `-n True if the length of string is non-zero.`

Comment: Why bother when you can just dump some code on here and someone can do it for you?

Answer (score 0):

`man test`

```
    -n STRING
           the length of STRING is nonzero
```

`man sed`

```
   s/regexp/replacement/
          Attempt to match regexp against the pattern space.  If successful, replace
          that portion matched with replacement.  The replacement  may  contain  the
          special  character  &  to refer to that portion of the pattern space which
          matched, and the special escapes \1 through \9 to refer to the correspond‐
          ing matching sub-expressions in the regexp.
```

Slash may be replaced with any char - e.g. question mark as in your example. So it means replace `/.*` (slash and the rest of the string) with nothing.

Comment: The first excerpt is useful, the second doesn't tell the full story. The important thing is that any character can be used as a delimiter instead of the `/`, in this case `?` has been used.